# How to continue with my Wolfram cloud basic?

Tags: web-access

I have this simple question but failed to find an answer on the internet.

So far (over a course of 6 months or so) I am using a free account called: Wolfram cloud basic. I use this to make some 3D graphs and publish them, then embed the links for public access. That's all I need.

Now, it said that all my files are going to expire within 7 days. And suggested me to upgrade.

When I clicked the suggested upgrade options, it gave me 3 options: Wolfram one, Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha Notebook edition.

My question: Which one should I consider if I only want to keep up my files on the cloud and have basic use (like plotting 3D graphs and embedding them somewhere)? Btw. I am a teacher coming from a third world country.

Thank for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6):

Both Mathematica and Wolfram|Alpha Notebook Edition are widely used by teachers and would be a good next step. If you have experience using Wolfram Language in the Wolfram Cloud, I recommend Mathematica. Mathematica has been a central tool for higher education across a variety of STEM disciplines and is used by millions of teachers and students worldwide. Not only can you run computations and create graphs with Mathematica, but also create documents and slideshows for your classes.

If you've been using free-form inputs to create your graphs in the Wolfram Cloud, Wolfram|Alpha Notebook Edition would be a great next step. It provides an easy-to-use interface where you can enter free-form input for all of your calculations and turn them into class materials and slideshows.

As a teacher, you'll qualify for academic pricing whichever product you choose. Send me an email at bautista_AT_wolfram.com to let me know what school you teach at, and I'd be happy check what type of discounts are available, and help connect you with folks here who can help you explore your options.